# Can PhpStorm's code checker be run from command line?

Tags: php, phpstorm, code-inspection

I'm attempting to implement some quality control on a project, and I've removed all warnings for my project according to a specific profile in the PhpStorm code inspector. Now I want to set up an automated check (maybe a git hook or Jenkins job) so that people don't add additional warnings.

Basically, what I need to do is to run PhpStorm's code > inspect functionality from the command line.

It appears that, by default, PhpStorm uses some kind of internal code inspection tool when I run code > inspect code. It has plugins for PHP Code Sniff and others, but I don't really want to use those. For example, PHP Code Sniff finds all kinds of spacing errors and such (it's a linter, after all), but it doesn't detect things like passing the wrong number of arguments to method signatures (i.e. the stuff I really care about).

So, is there any way to run PhpStorm's code inspection external to PhpStorm?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/64218290/175051

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm...

Looks like posting this question may have given me the clarity I needed to search for the correct answer. Looks like there's a way to do this outlined in the PHPStorm documentation:

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/command-line-code-inspector.html

Comment: I found the same thing, but found it creates like 99 xml files,  which I don't want to have to parse. Did you find a clean way to introduce this into jenkins or a daily graph or other biuld pipeline?