# Getting PHP lint / PhpStorm inspect errors every day from command line

Tags: php, phpstorm, static-analysis, sonarlint, phplint

Attempting to run a form of PHP linting from the command line, daily.

I've tried SonarLint - lovely in PhpStorm, but sadly they've apparently stopped supporting command line commands.

I tried to get PHPLint and `php -l` but I'm no php guru and was struggling with composer files.

Finally I looked at PhpStorm inspect - I can get it to create a directory of 99 types of errors, it seems, but then I'd have to either write a tool to grep the files and look /count errors, warnings to see if they're going up / down daily, or check it in the IDE, neither of which are particularly appealing.

There must be a tool that produces a nice simple output that I can incorporate as part of a build pipeline, graphing errors/warnings either daily or after each build?

Comment: [PHPStan](https://github.com/phpstan/phpstan), [Psalm](https://psalm.dev/) -- integration will be available in next major PhpStorm version (2020.3 -- currently in EAP stage if you want to try it now: https://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2020/10/phpstorm-2020-3-eap-2/). Also: [Phan](https://github.com/phan/phan), [NoVerify](https://github.com/VKCOM/noverify) etc. Any of them you can run in CLI / make it a part of your build process.

Comment: *"Finally I looked at PhpStorm inspect -... but then I'd have to either write a tool to grep the files and look /count errors, warnings to see if they're going up / down daily"* You can save results into a [JSON/XML format](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/command-line-code-inspector.html#options) which is much easier to parse using XML/JSON library (as compared to the plain text output).

Comment: This is used by JetBrains themselves (but they use [TeamCity](https://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/) -- their own CI tool; so they have some proper integration out of the box). Perhaps have a look at https://github.com/bentolor/idea-cli-inspector -- it was made to work with IntelliJ (Java) .. but may work with PHP results as well. Also: https://www.christianscheb.de/archives/808, https://dzone.com/articles/running-intellij-idea-in-jenkins

Comment: @LazyOne yes, I'd since found the XML output which made things a lot easier, thanks. Appreciate the idea-cli-inspector find too, will investigate.

Answer (score 1):

Try [PHPStan](https://github.com/phpstan/phpstan) (PHP Static Analysis Tool), which supports [CLI](https://phpstan.org/user-guide/command-line-usage) execution. This is also installed with `composer` (which is pretty much the default); most PHP IDE support `composer` out-of-the-box. Likely you won't find that many packages that won't be installed alike that, unless manually dropping them into an include path (this just won't give you the auto-loader capabilities).

Comment: `this just won't give you the auto-loader capabilities` that's not true.

Comment: To be precise, unless the auto-loader's class-list is being updated, it won't auto-load (this may still work without `composer`, but when adding new packages manually, they won't be picked up).

Answer (score -1):

You actually can run PhpStorm inspections from command line: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/command-line-code-inspector.html

Comment: Yes, I stated that in my question.